# JQuery-Plugin, let user run custom function in plugin

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I'm rather new to JQuery-Plugins, and I've tried to make a plugin that takes a function the user wrote and want to call it in a specific part of my plugin. Sadly I didn't really know what to look for, and all the turoials I've found so far didn't seem to give me the answer I was looking for.

I've got the following code for a JQuery-Plugin

```
$.fn.plugin = function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        //FUNCTION MIGHT GO IN HERE?
    }, options );

    this.each(function() {

        $(this).click(function(){
            //RUN FUNCTION USER DEFINES ON CALL
        });

    return this;
};
```

And I want the user to be able to call it like this:
(It will most likely be called otherwise, this code is just what I imagine it could be like, to make it more easy to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

```
$("p").plugin(doStuff("foo"));    
function doStuff(param1){
    console.log(param1);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That's not the proper way to provide a callback. It should be `.plugin(function() { doStuff("foo"); })`. Otherwise it will run `doStuff("foo")` when the user initializes the plugin, not when the plugin runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function should be in one of the options. Let's call it `onClick`.

```
$.fn.plugin = function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        onClick: function() {
            console.log("default");
        }
    }, options );

    this.each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            settings.onClick();
        });

    return this;
};
```

Then you would initialize the plugin by providing a function:

```
$("p").plugin({
    onClick: function() {
        doStuff("foo");
    }
});
```